# WinJS "ItemInvoked" event not firing

Tags: javascript, html, windows-store-apps, winjs

I am working with WinJS, while developing a Windows Phone App. The error that I am encountering is that the "itemInvoked" event listener in the code below (home.js) is not firing. It's almost as if the code doesn't exist. To fix this problem, I tried having a separate block of code for function and a separate line for setting the eventlistevener (For example, `function handler(event) {...} lw.addEventListener("itemInvoked", handler);`. I even tried doing it inline, for example: `lw.addEventListener("itemInvoked", function(event) {...});`. However, it didn't make any difference. The following is my code:

**basketball.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>groupedItemsPage</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <script src="//Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1/js/ui.js"></script>

    <script src="/pages/basketball/basketball.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="headertemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
        <span class="group-header win-type-x-large win-type-interactive" role="link" tabindex="-1">
            <span class="group-title win-type-ellipsis" data-win-bind="textContent: title"></span>
            <span class="group-chevron"></span>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="itemtemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
        <div class="item">
            <img id="image" class="item-image" src="#" data-win-bind="src: backgroundImage; alt: title" />
            <div id="info" class="item-overlay">
                <h4 id="title" class="item-title shadow" data-win-bind="textContent: title"></h4>
                <h6 id="subtitle" class="item-subtitle win-type-ellipsis shadow" data-win-bind="textContent: subtitle"></h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fragment groupeditemspage">
        <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
            <button id="backButton" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.BackButton"></button>
            <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
                <span class="pagetitle">Basketball Today</span>
            </h1>
        </header>
        <section class="content" aria-label="Main content" role="main" id="content">
            <div id="item" aria-label="List of groups" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{
                    layout: {type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout, groupHeaderPosition: 'top'},
                    selectionMode: 'none',
                    currentItem: {type: WinJS.UI.ObjectType.item, index: 0, hasFocus: true},
                    groupDataSource: Data.groups.dataSource,
                    groupHeaderTemplate: select('.headertemplate'),
                    itemDataSource: Data.items.dataSource,
                    itemTemplate: select('.itemtemplate'),
                    ongroupheaderinvoked: select('.pagecontrol').winControl.groupHeaderInvoked,
                    oniteminvoked: handler,
                    layout: {type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout, orientation: WinJS.UI.Orientation.vertical}
                }">
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**basketball.js**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/basketball/basketball.html", {
        ready: function (element, options) {
            var lw = document.getElementById("item").winControl;
            lw.addEventListener("iteminvoked", function (eventInfo) {
                console.log("hi");
                eventInfo.detail.itemPromise.done(function itemInvoked(item) {
                    WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/article/article.html", { newsItem: item.data });
                });
            });
        },
        unload: function () { },
        updateLayout: function (element) { }
    });
})();
```

It is worth noting that the entire code block of `addEventListener` doesn't seem to work. I tried adding `console.log("hi");` just before the page navigation to see if it was just the page navigation code which wasn't working, but it turns out that the console didn't log the "hi" either, which means that the entire event listener is not working.

Thank you for the help. I'm not entirely familiar with WinJS, hence I am making a mistake (this one might be a small, silly mistake).

Answer (score 0):

In your call to WinJS.UI.Pages.define, the first argument is the page ID, which must match the name of the HTML file you navigate to. In your code you have /pages/basketball/basketball.html, which doesn't match home.html.

As a result, home.html gets loaded just fine, but the ready method of the page control doesn't execute because you've defined it for basketball.html. So just make sure that first string arg to Pages.define matches the HTML file it exists for, namely "/pages/home/home.html" or such.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it seems that's a mistake on my part. It's in fact basketball.html and basketball.js, but I labeled it wrong in my original post. That said, is there anything else that looks wrong in the code above?

Comment: Can you confirm that the ready method is being called, and that the lw variable is getting initialized to non-null? That is, let's confirm that the ListView is instantiated so that there's something to add a listener to. (It should be OK, otherwise you'd see an exception.)

Comment: Secondly, I see that you have a "handler" assigned to the ListView in the HTML. Is that function being called? If "handler" doesn't exist, then remove that line from the data-win-options string. That could be confusing things.